# How to check length of value in onchange method in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Check value of Textfield in onChange method is empty or not if user remove all values from Textfield show in TextView "0".

Mean I want real time change and show change in TextView.

examples:

[when user add value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTlLO.png) its work fine

[when user remove all values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dss6P.png) here is

```
TextFormField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                          maxLines: 1,
                          controller: _paidController,

                      onChanged: (text) {
                        int newValue = int.parse(text);
                        setState(() {
                          if (text.trim().isEmpty) {
                            _paidController.text = "0";

                            print("set 0");

                            unpaid = 0;
                            paid = 0;

                          } else {
                            paid = newValue;
                            unpaid = grandTotal.toInt() - paid;
                          }
                        });
                      },

                      onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                        int newValue = int.parse(value);
                        setState(() {
                          if (value.isEmpty) {
                            paid = 0;
                            unpaid = grandTotal.toInt();
                          }
                          paid = newValue;
                          unpaid = grandTotal.toInt() - paid;
                        });
                      },
                      cursorColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: "Light",
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      ),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0XFF17145A),
                          fontFamily: "Light",
                        ),
                        labelText: 'Paid Amount',
                      ),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `text.trim().isEmpty` to check whether there has value on `textField`.

```
  onChanged: (text) {
      if (text.trim().isEmpty){
        _paidController.text = "0";  // set to zero if no value
        unpaid = grandTotal.toInt();
      }else{
        unpaid = grandTotal.toInt() - paid;
      }
   }
```

Comment: i would replace `if (text == "")` with `if (text.trim().isEmpty)`